# What are the good (and active) faucets for Rinkeby?

Tags: ether, testing, rinkeby, faucets

I am new to BlockChain Development and currently working on Smart Contracts. Can I know a place where I can get Test ETH to be used with Rinkeby please?
https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ is offline and other results came with google also same.
Thanks

Comment: Hey there! With the Ethereum merge, Goerli is the only Ethereum testnet running. All others including Rinkeby have been deprecated. 

If you need any free Goerli testETH, Alchemy has a reliable faucet - https://goerlifaucet.com/. 




If you have Rinkeby, here's how to migrate over to Goerli. https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/migrate-from-rinkeby-to-goerli/?a=1ebaf27421.

Answer (score 1):

I use chainlink faucets all the time. Although the amount is low, it is always up and running.

https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby